# deploy an artefact on 2 different nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, devops

I'm currently facing an issue while working on a project. My organization currently has more than one Nexus in order to deploy our artifacts. Once we finish developing our libraries, we need to deploy this artifact on two different Nexus. I haven't found a clean way to do it. Has anyone come across the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't do this. Instead, you deploy to just one Nexus and let the other Nexus proxy the relevant repositories of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy an existing artifact to Nexus using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Just run this twice and deploy file to two different servers.